# how to remove unwated \" from tinyMCE links

Tags: javascript, tinymce

when added a link to TinyMCE it changes from http:/mylink.com to mywebsite.com/"http:/mylink.com

currently tinymce is setup as

```
        tinymce.init({
            selector: '#admin-offer-editor',
            plugins: 'code link lists',
            toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bullist numlist | bold italic underline | alignleft | aligncenter | alignright | link | code',
            menubar: false,
            link_context_toolbar: true,
            link_default_protocol: "https",
            convert_urls: false,
            link_assume_external_targets: true,
                     });
```

Comment: `http:/mylink.com` is not a valid URL, so it's treated as a path.

Comment: This happens with all websites. so https://www.gtmetrix.com/ would become mywebsite.com/"https:/www.gtmetrix.com/ if there is https:// or www. at the start or not